# Appropriate image file format for losslessly compressing series of screenshots

Tags: c++, image, video, image-processing, compression

I am building an application which takes a great many number of screenshots during the process of "recording" operations performed by the user on the windows desktop.

For obvious reasons I'd like to store this data in as efficient a manner as possible.

At first I thought about using the PNG format to get this done. But I stumbled upon this: http://www.olegkikin.com/png_optimizers/

The best algorithms only managed a 3 to 5 percent improvement on an image of GUI icons. This is highly discouraging and reveals that I'm going to need to do better because just using PNG will not allow me to use previous frames to help the compression ratio. The filesize will continue to grow linearly with time.

I thought about solving this with a bit of a hack: Just save the frames in groups of some number, side by side. For example I could just store the content of 10 1280x1024 captures in a single 1280x10240 image, then the compression should be able to take advantage of repetitions across adjacent images.

But the problem with this is that the algorithms used to compress PNG are not designed for this. I am arbitrarily placing images at 1024 pixel intervals from each other, and only 10 of them can be grouped together at a time. From what I have gathered after a few minutes scanning the PNG spec, the compression operates on individual scanlines (which are filtered) and then chunked together, so there is actually no way that info from 1024 pixels above could be referenced from down below.

So I've found the MNG format which extends PNG to allow animations. This is much more appropriate for what I am doing.

One thing that I am worried about is how much support there is for "extending" an image/animation with new frames. The nature of the data generation in my application is that new frames get added to a list periodically. But I do have a simple semi-solution to this problem, which is to cache a chunk of recently generated data and incrementally produce an "animation", say, every 10 frames. This will allow me to tie up only 10 frames' worth of uncompressed image data in RAM, not as good as offloading it to the filesystem immediately, but it's not terrible. After the entire process is complete (or even using free cycles in a free thread, during execution) I can easily go back and stitch the groups of 10 together, if it's even worth the effort to do it.

Here is my actual question that everything has been leading up to. Is MNG the best format for my requirements? Those reqs are: 1. C/C++ implementation available with a permissive license, 2. 24/32 bit color, 4+ megapixel (some folks run 30 inch monitors) resolution, 3. lossless or near-lossless (retains text clarity) compression with provisions to reference previous frames to aid that compression.

For example, here is another option that I have thought about: video codecs. I'd like to have lossless quality, but I have seen examples of h.264/x264 reproducing remarkably sharp stills, and its performance is such that I can capture at a much faster interval. I suspect that I will just need to implement both of these and do my own benchmarking to adequately satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to a PNG compression implementation, you could easily optimize the compression without having to use the MNG format by just preprocessing the "next" image as a difference with the previous one. This is naive but effective if the screenshots don't change much, and compression of "almost empty" PNGs will decrease a lot the storage space required.

Comment: This is good insight. I started reading MNG docs and noticed they have something called a "Delta-PNG" which is just as it sounds. It's dead simple conceptually (which is great), and definitely addresses the issues. I will accept this answer if nobody chimes in with some interesting info regarding video streams.